# How to sort my combobox starting from last to first c# database access?

Tags: c#, database

[Sorted to 5-1??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKiG7.png)

I want to sort my combobox starting from the last to first, but I don't if is there a code for it?

Comment: Use LINQ and reverse the array you are binding to combobox

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes sir ill follow the way to ask question i'm sorry if i'm clumsy

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

### Option 1:

```
DataView dataView = new DataView(dtData);
dataView.Sort = "Id DESC";

ddlOptions.DataSource = dataView;
ddlOptions.DataTextField = "Title";
ddlOptions.DataValueField = "Id";
ddlOptions.DataBind();
```

### Option 2:

```
ddlOptions.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"].OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);
```

Hope this helps.